# Roulette selection

Tags: android, roulette-wheel-selection

i'm using roulette selection algorithm for android using the code bellow :

```
//int n=4;
//double [] weight = new double [n];
//weight[0]=9;
//weight[1]=8;
//weight[2]=10;
//weight[3]=1;
public void Roulette(double weight[],double max_weight){
    int index=0;
    while (true){
        index= (int)(weight.length*Math.random());
        if(Math.random()<weight[index]/max_weight) {break;}
    }
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Chosen="+index,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

is it possible to create (graphique and code) something like showed in the figure bellow using android studio ?

[image]

Comment: you can inflate a drawable and paint it with different colors programatically, but you will need an xml to define different portions of the graphic to be painted

Comment: `public static void main(String [] args) {` doesn't look like Android code. Are you sure?

Comment: `is it possible to create` sure, it is possible. What is the problem to create it for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some charts for android, for example this:
[MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

Comment: i need something could spin and stop in specific value

Comment: so you can try this wheels I found some:
https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu
https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView